# Leer triangulo superior de una matriz e imprimirlo por pantalla

Tags: c

`Hola buenas,`quisiera saber por qué no me funciona este pequeño programa.
Tengo que: Leer el triangulo superior de la matriz e imprimirlo por pantalla.

De momento tengo esto, pero el problema es que a la hora de imprimir/leer (no estoy muy seguro donde da el problema), la matriz como que se me queda en bucle infinito y no hace nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 3

void leer_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]);
void imprimir_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]);

    void main () {

        float matriz [DIM][DIM];

        printf ("Introduce una matriz 3x3: ");
        leer_matriz_superior (matriz);
        imprimir_matriz_superior (matriz);
    }


    // Función 1.

    void leer_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i = DIM -2; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j = DIM - 1; j ++) {
                scanf ("%f", &matriz [i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Función 2.

    void imprimir_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i = DIM - 2; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j = DIM - 1; j ++) {
                printf ("%6.0f", matriz [i][j]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }
```

El compilador no da error, y he revisado las condiciones del bucle y creo que están correctas, ¿alguna solución?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Editado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 3

void leer_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]);
void imprimir_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]);

    void main () {

        float matriz [DIM][DIM];

        printf ("Introduce una matriz 3x3: ");
        leer_matriz_superior (matriz);
        imprimir_matriz_superior (matriz);
    }


    // Funció 1.

    void leer_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                scanf ("%f", &matriz [i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Funció 2.

    void imprimir_matriz_superior (float matriz [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i = DIM - 2; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j = DIM - 1; j ++) {
                printf ("%6.0f", matriz [i][j]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las condiciones del bucle `for`, en el segundo parámetro estas asignando a `i` y `j` a `DIM - 2` y `DIM - 1` respectivamente, cuando debería ser menor que o igual que `DIM - 1`.

Es decir, al hacer `i = DIM - 2` o `j = DIM -1` siempre van a tomar ese valor y no van a salir del bucle, ya que haces una asignación y no tiene condición de parada, deberías cambiarlo por `i <= DIM - 2` y `j <= DIM - 1`

Comment: Estas leyendo mal la matriz, para leerla debería ser desde `i = 0` hasta `i < DIM` y con la `j` igual, ya que quieres leer todas las posiciones. El bucle para imprimir diría que si que está bien para una matriz de 3x3, ya que leyendola como te digo el resultado si es `2, 6, 3`

Comment: Al fin, ya me funciona.
¿Entonces si quiero leer el triángulo superior o inferior de una matriz tengo que leer toda la matriz? Es que por más que intento comprenderlo no le encuentro lógica, si quiero leer solo el triangulo superior, solo deberé leer el triángulo superior, ¿no?

Comment: A lo que tu llamas leer es lo que hace la segunda función, lee el triangulo superior y lo muestra por pantalla. La primera función lo que hace es recibir/leer los datos que ponga el usuario en pantalla, y lo que le estas pidiendo es la matriz entera y guardándola, por lo que tienes que recibir/leer todos los datos de la matriz. Te sugiero que ahora que lo has resuelto elimines todos los comentarios que veas innecesarios para resolver el problema, ya que no ayudan al correcto visionado de la pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchísimas gracias, dejaré este último por si alguno tiene la misma duda que yo.
Gracias de nuevo, amigo.